# Installing Anaconda on Ubuntu does not work

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

Currently, I am watching an online course for python. That course is using Anaconda for the libraries etc.

Installing Anaconda on Windows 7 works perfectly fine. But I want to use all of the Stuff on Ubuntu since Linux works better for the stuff I want to develop.
Everything works fine from the point of downloading Anaconda for Linux, running it in the terminal and installing it. 
The installations return Success "Thanks for installing Anaconda3!"

But from that point on nothing works. The installed folder with its files is there. But I cannot run the programm from the terminal, nor from a simple double-click on the symbol. Cause there is no symbol anywhere for it. Running it through the terminal by using the command "anaconda notebook", "Anaconda" etc. all don't work. 
It acts like the programm isn't installed. Even tho it is. I reinstalled it several times. But it all doesn't work. I'm starting to get mad tbh...

Ubuntu runs over a virtual machine if that is important. VM Ware Workstation v14

Comment: did you check your path? echo $PATH does it contain any link to anaconda directory?

Comment: First make sure your Anaconda install is in your path. Also the command for Anaconda in the terminal is `conda`

Comment: Have you opened a new shell since installing? If the installer adds Anaconda to your PATH by modifying your shell profile files, it won't be available until you source the profile (which you can do manually from your current shell session, but it's easier to just create a new one).

Comment: The name of the Anaconda IDE is `spyder`. That's what you should be starting.

Comment: @Nagashayan yes, anaconda is shown in the directory when using echo $PATH

Comment: The Anaconda Installation Guide says using the command "anaconda-naviagator" is what you use to open it. Which i used the whole time, and it said programm not found etc. But now for some reason it works...so PC logic i guess

Comment: did you try conda command?

Comment: @Nagashayan i did. But it didnt worked. It made my cursour go to a new line and then didnt do anything. But now it just worked with the (by the guide recommended) "anaconda-navigator" command. which didnt worked before..but now it does..no idea why really